# How can I have automatically updating copies of charts?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have been doing some more complex work with Excel (different tabs/worksheets, etc.).

Now I have some charts from one worksheet that I'd like to kind of embed in the other worksheets for the purpose of comparing the chart of one situation with the original charts from the other worksheets.

There seems to be no actual possibility of pasting a chart in a way that when the original is changed (be it the data or the colors of the different series etc.) that the copies change automatically.

Thus, currently I find myself updating 5 or 6 worksheets each time when I change something in the original chart.

I see you can embed charts into Word and Powerpoint etc. Is a similar thing possible within Excel???

Comment: Sure, but when I add series or change something in the formatting of the original chart etc. it will not change in the copies. I want the copy to be completely linked to the original. Not just to the original _data_.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the **Excel Camera Tool** to take a snapshot of cells or charts. Once they are placed where you like, they will automatically update whenever the original is changed.

[Here are instructions](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/camera-tool-function-in-excel-2010/) how to use it. It's a handy tool.

Note: When using it to take a snapshot of the chart, select the cells surrounding the chart in order to get the shot. Selecting just the chart doesn't work.

Comment: That's slick! :)  Why is that Camera buried so deep Microsoft?? :/

Comment: Probably thought we'd abuse it. LOL

Comment: The fact it updates the data while showing it on a 3D angle is crazy cool -- and almost useful. ;)